# VSCode keeps prefixing class with Global

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    class iphone{
        public $name;
        public $email;

        public function __construct($n , $e)
        {
            $this->name = $n;
            $this->email= $e;
        }

        public function __clone()
        {
            $this->name = clone $this->name;
        }

    }
```

, and I want to write

```
$main = new iphone("zico" , "aa@a.a");
```

However when I try to type `iphone` VSCode transforms the class name into `GlobalIphone` and adds a `use` statement at the top of the code:

```
use iphone as GlobalIphone;
```

[image]

I want VSCode to write the name of the class without any additions, how do I make it do this?

Comment: Assuming you can override it?

Comment: You are using the iphone class in your own iphone class. That's just wrong. You can `use iphone` in *other classes* than this class, but you can't do `use iphone` in a class that's called `iphone`.        In which php file or class are you doing this: `$main = new iphone("zico" , "aa@a.a");`

Answer (score 2):

As @underdog pointed out in the comments, the problem was that there were other classes with the same name in another php file:

[image: other classes with same name]

When I changed the name of my class, the `Global` prefix was no longer automatically added by VSCode.

[image: using different class name]